# end of line error in c error message saying missing ; after ( token

Tags: c, line, printf

```
# include <stdio.h>
double simpleInterest (double Princ, double Rate, int Time)
{
     double value;
     value = Princ*Rate*Time;
     retrun value;
}
int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
  printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(100,0.05,1);
  printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(1,0.01,10);
}
```

I get a error saying expected';' before ')' token but i dont understand i've put a ; after each line. Should i put any other somewhere else ?

Comment: Missing `return` from `main()`.

Answer (score 6):

```
  printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(100,0.05,1);
  printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(1,0.01,10);
                                                       ^
```

missing closing parentheses in the two functions calls.

And:

```
%5.2
```

You are probably missing a conversion specifier here.

And also:

```
 retrun value;
```

typo in keyword here...

Please re-read your code before submitting questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Missing closing parenthesis

```
printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(100,0.05,1) );
                                                      ^^
  printf ("value is £%5.2\n", simpleInterest(1,0.01,10) );
                                                        ^^
```

Always better to declare function.

```
retrun value; // typo
```

And
use `%5.2f` format specifier.